# help...! same page file upload to mysql

Tags: php, fopen

so i decided against using uploadify as i could not get any help on it. i've been now trying to implement a simpler solution. but unfortunately i cannot seem to process the upload code on a single page without receiving the following error:

> Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]:
>   Filename cannot be empty in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\speedycms\manageclient.php
>   on line 205
>
> Warning: fread() expects parameter 1
>   to be resource, boolean given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\speedycms\manageclient.php
>   on line 206
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1
>   to be resource, boolean given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\speedycms\manageclient.php
>   on line 208 Error, query failed

this is the code i've been trying to get to work... can you suggest any means of getting it all to work on a single page rather than splitting it up into two apart from ajax (im not too familiar with that)... its all on a single page

any help would be appreciated!

```
         <!-- upload file --->

             <?php
                     if (array_key_exists('uploadfile',$_POST)) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }

    $uploadQry = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, content ) ".
    "VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";

    mysql_query($uploadQry) or die('Error, query failed'); 

    echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
    exit;
                     }
    ?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?id=' . intval($client_id); ?>">
    <p>
         <b>File Upload</b></p>
    <p>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
<input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile"><BR />
               <input type="hidden" name="uploadfile" value="1"/> 
<input name="upload" type="submit" id="upload" value=" Upload ">
    </p>
    <p>      <a href="#viewFiles" class="form" rel="facebox">View files</a>

    </p>
    <div id="viewFiles" style="display:none;" rel="facebox"> 
      <div style="width:300px; height: 300px;"></div></div></form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [set the correct encoding of your form](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) to enable file uploads:

```
<!-- The data encoding type, enctype, MUST be specified as below -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
    ...
</form>
```

**Edit**:  `Filename cannot be empty` is telling you that you have not specified the file name in your first call to fopen - you're passing in $tmpName to that method, which is assigned from `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`.

The only reason I can think of for `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` to be empty is that you haven't actually uploaded a file?

Comment: i've made the changes as you have recommended but im still getting the same error message... i didnt notice that tho.. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that in

```
$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
```

$tmpName is blank (or NULL).

Try looking in $_FILES to see what you've got:

```
print serialize($_FILES);
```